# jQuery JSONP not working anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I have been trying to load a JSON file from a cross-domain server. I've tried examples from stackoverflow and from the jQuery docs. I did get it working in a previous project, but now it strangely does not. The error returned from jQuery is unreadable to me. What can possibly go wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Start loading");
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "http://www.nightoferror.nl/data/data.json", 
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true,
      error: function(data) {
        console.log('error', data);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success', data);
      }
});
```

});

And the erratic JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuyJV/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Content-Type:application/javascript
```

rather than `Content-Type:application/json;`

Could it be because your file is named `.js`, that Apache is serving the content type itself?

Try changing the file type, to JSON and setting up Apache to serve that filetype with the correct MimeType.

I found this using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)  - A HTTP Debugger.. open Fiddler(2), make your request in your browser and Fiddler2 then picks it up. From there, just checked the response for your file.

[image]It looks like your server is returning the response as "Application/Javascript"

Comment: Thanks, I changed the file to data/data.json in the jsfiddle. Still no result.

Comment: It looks like it's still down to the `Content-Type` being returned, it's being returned as `text/plain`, not JSON...

Comment: Thanks! It does look like that is the source of the problem. How did you find this?

Comment: I've updated the answer - I used Fiddler2 - Say hi to your new best friend!

Comment: Chrome/FF/Safari all have Web/Dev tools which can show this info (Chrome/Safari both use WebKit, which produces the same tools).

These all have a 'Network' tab which can produce similar results :)